# Comparing strings which are not exactly same

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to compare to strings. But isEqualToString is not useful for me. Because i don't want them to be exactly same. İf one of my strings is Lev Tolstoy and the other one is just Tolstoy; i want them to be matched. Any ideas?

Comment: That's far too fuzzy as a specification. Do you want all strings that have one word in common to match? Or do you want to match only names?

Comment: Do you have any idea how it will ignore the characters are big or small. I am getting the value from textfield. If users write small, they don't match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you always know the Substring you're looking for, try this (the order of the words doesn't matter, so even 'Tolstoy Lev' would match):

```
NSString *string = @"Lev Tolstoy";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"Tolstoy"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain 'Tolstoy'");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains 'Tolstoy'!");
}
```

For more information about `rangeOfString:` take a look at Apples [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for `NSString`

For more complex situations take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28string_functions%29

Comment: it worked. Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea how it will ignore the characters are big or small. I am getting the value from textfield. If users write small, they don't match.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options provided by [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

For your case, you could use hasSuffix like this:

```
NSString* str = @"Lev Tolstoy"
NSString* suffix = @"Tolstoy"
if ([str hasSuffix:suffix]) {
   // do something useful
}
```

There are many other options depending on what your test will be including searching for substrings with rangeOfString, or hasPrefix.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [approximate / fuzzy string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) where, rather than a straight-forward `isEqual:` function that returns a `BOOL` based on exact match, you have two functions (on `NSString`), with prototypes along the lines of:

```
- (NSUInteger)distanceToString:(NSString *)otherString;
- (BOOL)isSufficientlyCloseTo:(NSString *)otherString;
```

The second is a convenience wrapper, implemented something like:

```
- (BOOL)isSufficientlyCloseTo:(NSString *)otherString {
    return [self distanceToString:otherString] <= MY_MAGIC_THRESHOLD;
}
```

So you basically need a distance function, and a threshold for equality. A simple example of the distance function would be [the Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) - you then need to, through experimentation, choose a value for `MY_MAGIC_THRESHOLD` such that you're happy with the outcome.